# Creating Ordered Lists with HTML5 and/or CSS that are Safe for Screen-Readers?

Tags: css, html, accessibility, section508, wcag2.0

I'm working on a project where accessibility is of prime importance.  There's frequent reference to **parts** of an ordered list and I'm not sure how to mark it up.

I made have a [jsfiddle demo of referencing an ordered list with CSS Counters](http://jsfiddle.net/3vrnwk40/1/) that I would like to implement, but I'm not entirely sure how accessible it is.  I'm getting mixed results from my own research.

I would like to use the HTML5  feature, but the decimal aspect is important.

If I marked it up with screen-reader only tags (ie `<li><span class="sr-only">3.5<span> ... </li>`) then  it's likely that the numbers will be double read.  Of course, I'm also worried about them not being read at all...

Is there a best practice surrounding this challenge?

Comment: Test, test and test: on Windows you can test with NVDA (free software) and on OS X with VoiceOver. JAWS license forbids a developer to use it for test purpose even if it'll work for 40 minutes (do whatever you want with this. I don't test with JAWS). EDIT: VoiceOver on iOS may have different results than on OS X and on Android you've TalkBack

Answer (score 1):

I tested your jsfiddle with NVDA in Firefox and it read every list item the way I would expect. I agree with FelipeAIs that you should test with other screen-reader software too as they vary a lot in their interpretation.

MDN shows browser support for counter CSS going back as far as IE8: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-reset

If you find that only some screenreaders are picking it up, try using the start attribute as a fallback.

Comment: Thanks for running the test stringy.  I'm definitely concerned about WCAG failure F87 regarding use of the :before and :after pseudo-elements.  Do you think the start attribute is enough of a fallback?

Comment: I think so, I think it's fairly robust and well supported. (sorry for not replying sooner!) A different fallback would be to mention that the lists are in decimals before the list starts - sort of as a just-in-case heads up for non-sighted people. It's a bit difficult to slip in that kind of detail subtly, but if there's already an explanation of where to find content it might work there :)